# mysql why the subquery return total balance of all customers instead of balance for individual customer

Tags: mysql, subquery

May someone help me with this subquery please?

The table account has the `customer id`, `account id` and the `balance` for each account.

The table customer has the `customer id`, `customer city` and `customer type` information.

I want to create a subquery that shows the sum of balance for individual customer between 5000 and 10000.

When I run the command, the result for sum balance for customer 4,7 and 11 are actually the sum for all customers..

The sum of available balance for customer 4 should be 6,788.

17,0754 is the sum for all customers..

Where went wrong?

Thank you so much.

```
SELECT c.cust_id,c.cust_type_cd,c.city,sum(a.avail_balance)    
FROM customer c,account a
WHERE (SELECT sum(a.avail_balance)                                               
       FROM account a                                                                                
       WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id)                                                                           
BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000                                                                          
GROUP BY c.cust_id;
```

Comment: please provide the table's structure and some sample data

Comment: See HAVING, which comes after GROUP BY

Comment: thank you. I changed where to Having command. And use inner join. problem solved. just wonder when should i use where, and when should I use having? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

```
SELECT tab2.cust_id,city, cust_type_cd,total_avail_balance FROM
customer RIGHT JOIN (SELECT SUM(avail_balance) total_avail_balance,cust_id
FROM `account` GROUP BY 2 HAVING SUM(avail_balance) BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000) tab2
ON tab2.cust_id = customer.cust_id;
```

Hope it will satisfy your requirement!

Comment: yes, i use having and inner join. Problem solved. Just wonder when should I use having and when should i use where? thank you Suresh.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. Indeed after i change the "where" to "having", and use INNER JOIN. I manage to solve the problem. Here is the updated command. Just wonder when should we use "where" and when should we use "having"?

```
SELECT c.cust_id,c.cust_type_cd,c.city,sum(a.avail_balance)                         
 from customer c INNER JOIN account a                                                 
 ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id                                                                                 
   GROUP BY c.cust_id                                                             
   HAVING sum(a.avail_balance) BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000;
```